# Método de Pagamento divido entre contas

Tags: laravel

Estou desenvolvendo um E-commerce em que nele terá várias marcas, cada marca terá sua devida integração com PagSeguro, a dúvida em questão é como separar os valores de cada marca no final da compra e trazer apenas uma compra para o usuário final?

Explicando melhor:

Tenho duas marcas na minha loja, cada loja tem 1 produto. Eu como usuário final compro os dois produtos, um de cada marca, no meu cartão vem apenas uma compra (Empresa X). Porém para essas empresas ela recebem o valor de cada produto em seu PagSeguro.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Raank, não venho com sua resposta definitiva, mas gostaria de compartilhar contigo um ponto pelo qual você deve se atentar:

Estude a **[circular 3.682](https://www.bcb.gov.br/pre/normativos/busca/normativo.asp?tipo=circ&ano=2013&numero=3682) de 2013 do BACEN**. Ela regulamenta sobre liquidação para marketplaces e facilitadoras, talvez você esteja no escopo - e mesmo que não vá se preocupar com isso agora, é uma regulamentação e amanha ou depois você terá que colocar em pratica.

A Moip tem um documento legal sobre isso, veja nesse [link](https://moip.com.br/blog/tudo-que-voce-precisa-saber-sobre-nova-regulamentacao-do-banco-central-para-marketplaces/). Eles, inclusive, tem um produto que pode te ajudar.

*Não, essa não é uma 'resposta propaganda', é apenas um informativo que pode te ajudar.*

Com relação ao slip que você precisa fazer - identifique os produtos por empresa, armazene os pedidos e após o pagamento aprovado, faça a divisão do valor atribuindo a cada pedido ao valor correspondente ao deposito em conta das diferentes lojas. Você deve ter sua estrutura de contas para liquidação dos estabelecimentos, não é?

Comment: E essa plataforma tem Lib para Laravel?

Comment: @Raank,

Veja o GitHub deles: https://github.com/moip/moip-sdk-php

Comment: Tem sim, vou usa-lo agora como meio de pagamento para MarketPlace, obrigado!